# Defining Sequentially Rationalizable Strategies

Tags: game-theory

The definition of a rationalizable strategy is given in "A Course in Game Theory" by Osborne & Rubinstein on Chapter 4 as Definition 54.1 in the book (which is freely available at [books.osborne.economics.utoronto.ca](http://books.osborne.economics.utoronto.ca)), as a formalization of the intuition that it is a common belief of all players that a player will assign zero probability to choosing a strategy which is not a best response to what he believes to be the strategies of all other players. It turns out that this definition is unsatisfactory for extensive-form games, because there are strategies that are eliminated via backward induction but are rationalizable (and even part of a Nash equilibrium).

Here's the excerpt from the book that really matters to my question:
[Book Snapshot of the Definition of Rationalizability](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3Ooz.png)

I'd like to define the notion of "sequential rationalizability" that corresponds to sequential equilibrium in analogous sense that "rationalizability" corresponds to Nash equilibrium.

My intuition is that the new definition is simply rationalizability **plus an extra assumption**: It is a common belief of all players (at all states of the game) that a player's "belief" (at an information state where he plays) about the strategies of all other players assigns zero probability to all strategies that are not consistent with his arriving at the information state where he's being.

Notice that this definition requires the "rationalizable set of beliefs" be given for each player **at each information set where he plays.** This is necessary, because if a belief of a player (at one state) assigns zero probability to a move of another player, then at a(nother) state that is only consistent to that move having already occurred, he is forced to have a different "belief" (that is, he should revise his belief upon realizing that an event he previously believed to be impossible has occurred).

Can you give a definition of this "sequential rationalizability" **that is analogous to Definition 54.1** of the book? I've yet to find such an idea in the literature. There are many different ideas people proposed of what sequential rationalizability should be, and some try to derive directly from logical models of the players' behaviors (notice that, on the other hand, Osborne & Rubinstein derives Definition 54.1 as a mathematical formalization that "intuitively follows" from the immediately preceding intuition given in the book before that definition). Please offer a definition that corresponds to (the intution given in the book, plus:) the intuition I've given above.

Comment: We know that Nash Equilibrium is a subset of rationalisable stragies. And then sequential rationality allows us to further refine the set of Nash equilibrium and we arrive at Subgame Perfect Nash Equilibrium. I don't think the notion of 'sequentially rationalizable strategies" exists; I believe it's an assumption or that we make to arrive at Subgame perfect outcomes which are basically strategies?

Comment: Subgame perfection is a bogus ad-hoc notion, that can be easily tricked to becoming as unsatisfactory as irrational Nash equilibria. (Many authors define subgame perfection only for perfect-information games, but let's pick up the definition by Roger B. Myerson in "Game Theory: Analysis of Conflict", who defines it for imperfect-information games as well.)

Comment: Suppose that you have a perfect-information game (for which subgame perfection is completely satisfactory and coincides with backward induction). Then build a new game by having all the terminal nodes of the original game controlled by a new "dummy" player, in one information set. This player is then given only one choice at this information set, corresponding to edges that go to new terminal nodes that are identical to the original ones.

Comment: Intuitively, this new game is identical to the original one, because the "dummy" player actually has no choice but bring the original play to its end. But the game has suddenly become one without any proper subgames, so backward induction no more preserves all subgame-perfect equilibria, and irrational Nash equilibria pop up into existence again as being subgame-perfect.

Comment: (This point is made in Figure 4.11, page 185 of Myerson.) You can try to refine the definition of subgame-perfect equilibria to avoid this problem, but then you will immediately realize that other tricks will counter your attempt, and you will soon realize that trying to patch up the definition here and there will not bring you anywhere. So what we really need are sequential equilibria (which are robust and immune to such cheap tricks), not subgame-perfect equilibria.